# error during building ear project with Maven 3

Tags: java, maven

I have the tree 
pom.xml
.presentation(ear)
..business(war)
..integration(jar)

when i try to build the  ear (presentation) i get this error i don't understand why the artifact presentation should be a dependency and a dependency of what exactly ?   :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project presentation: Artifact[war:presentaion:presentation] is not a dependency of the project. ->Help
```

ear: pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>presentation</groupId>
  <artifactId>presentation</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
   <parent>
  <groupId>MyProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1</version>
  </parent>

<build>
  <plugins>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
        <modules>
          <webModule>
            <groupId>presentaion</groupId>
            <artifactId>presentation</artifactId>
            <bundleFileName>presentation.war</bundleFileName>
            <contextRoot>/presentation</contextRoot>
          </webModule>
          <jarModule>
            <groupId>integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
           <bundleFileName>integration.jar</bundleFileName>
          </jarModule>
        </modules>
        <displayName>My Project</displayName>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <finalName>presentation</finalName>
</build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>business</groupId>
        <artifactId>business</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>integration</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: "presentaion" is a typo, maybe you are linking to a different module name

Comment: probably the child's pom.xml have the groupid "presentation" :)

Comment: yes thank you :) ... actually i fixed the error i should put business instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current .pom you are building an ear and you are giving the same ear as a warModule.

You should give a .war artefact for webmodule in the ear-plugin